Drogon CLI cannot generete model
The drogon CLI does not recognize the config file.
drogon_ctl create model -f config.json
Create model
No such file or directory : config.json
ls
"All the needed files"
cat config.json
"All the needed stuff"
I have tried
ls -l config.json chmod +r config.json

You must pass model.json instead of config.json. Also, you need to pass <model_path>. Try drogon_ctl help create, and you can refer to some usages.
